# What's the best c implementation of the C++ vector?

Tags: c, arrays, vector

I've been looking into using C over C++ as I find it cleaner and the main thing I find it to lack is a vector like array.

What is the best implementation of this?

I want to just be able to call something like vector_create, vector_at, vector_add, etc.

Comment: I don't see how that would make code clearer or cleaner. This is like making a function to add 2 numbers. C will still be C, it's not OOP.

Comment: Probably your own. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) is decent starting point.

Comment: The two advantages that the stl  brings for collection types is templates and RIIA;  Since there's no way to express either in C, there's not much incentive to recreate the STL in C.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDIT**

This answer is from a million years ago, but at some point, I actually implemented a macro-based, efficient, type-safe vector work-alike in C that covers all the typical features and needs. You can find it here:

https://github.com/eteran/c-vector

Original answer below.

---

What about a vector are you looking to replicate? I mean in the end, it all boils down to something like this:

```
int *create_vector(size_t n) {
    return malloc(n * sizeof(int));
}

void delete_vector(int *v) {
    free(v);
}

int *resize_vector(int *v, size_t n) {
    return realloc(v, n * sizeof(int));
    /* returns NULL on failure here */
}
```

You could wrap this all up in a struct, so it "knows its size" too, but you'd have to do it for every type (macros here?), but that seems a little uneccessary... Perhaps something like this:

```
typedef struct {
    size_t size;
    int *data;
} int_vector;

int_vector *create_vector(size_t n) {
    int_vector *p = malloc(sizeof(int_vector));
    if(p) {
        p->data = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
        p->size = n;
    }
    return p;
}

void delete_vector(int_vector *v) {
    if(v) {
        free(v->data);
        free(v);
    }
}

size_t resize_vector(int_vector *v, size_t n) {
    if(v) {
        int *p = realloc(v->data, n * sizeof(int));
        if(p) {
            v->data = p;
            v->size = n;
        }
        return v->size;
    }
    return 0;
}

int get_vector(int_vector *v, size_t n) {
    if(v && n < v->size) {
        return v->data[n];
    }
    /* return some error value, i'm doing -1 here, 
     * std::vector would throw an exception if using at() 
     * or have UB if using [] */
    return -1;
}

void set_vector(int_vector *v, size_t n, int x) {
    if(v) {
        if(n >= v->size) {
            resize_vector(v, n);
        }
        v->data[n] = x;
    }
}
```

After which, you could do:

```
int_vector *v = create_vector(10);
set_vector(v, 0, 123);
```

I dunno, it just doesn't seem worth the effort.

Comment: Gotta be careful to avoid introducing O(N**2) behavior though. Also I've never seen that kind of test for the return value of `realloc`, you probably got it right, but I find it kind of odd.

Comment: I would like it to be efficient and also reallocate the memory for me, keeping track of the size

Comment: @Evan: With `std::vector` you can keep making your vector 1 element bigger and still keep it O(N) your implementation currently won't (what I was referring to in my first comment). The usual way is keep track of the capacity of the vector aside from it's current size and doubling the capacity when it's filled (See the wikipedia link in my comment to the OP).

Comment: @Will03uk: that, you can't have unless you are willing to only access the "vector" through function calls. C++ does this with operator overloading (specifically, `operator[]`), which C doesn't have.

Comment: @user786653: yea, this is **clearly**, the naive implementation. I just wanted to illustrate what it would look like in concept, and why it probably isn't worth it ;-).

Comment: You definitely want to distinguish "capacity" from "size" so that you can implement a proper O(1) "push_back" equivalent.  The easiest way to do this is to make the capacity always be a power of 2.  (Or just stick with C++ since somebody else already figured this out for you, not to mention lots of other things that you have not even imagined yet.)

Comment: @Evan I was expecting to have to use functions

Comment: @Nemo, @user786653: While you are both probably right that it is best to have a conept of capacity and size like `std::vector`. Two things: #1 the point of my answer was not to give a complete solution, but to demonstrate the concept. #2 it occurs to me now, that `realloc` is allowed to resize an existing block in place if it has enough slack at the end. This may make the small increases in size not quite as bad as one might think. But You are right that doing powers of 2 would likely be best.

Comment: @user786653: I think you are right that my `realloc` check was a bit off, now that think about it. I don't think i need to explicitly `free` the old data if the block successfully resized.

Comment: `int *p = realloc(v->data, n * sizeof(int)); if(p) { p->data = p; p->size = n; } return v->size;` doesn't make sense to me... shoudn't it be: `if (p) { v->data = p; ... }`

Comment: @isdev, it is resizing the malloced array `v->data` and if it does so successfully, sets `v->data` to the new resized array.

Answer (score 1):

The most complete effort I know of to create a comprehensive set of utility types in C is [GLib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLib).  For your specific needs it provides `g_array_new`, `g_array_append_val` and so on.  See [GLib Array Documentation](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/glib/glib-Arrays.html).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than going off on a tangent in the comments to [@EvanTeran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826163/whats-the-best-c-implementation-of-the-c-vector/7826201#7826201) I figured I'd submit a longer reply here.

As various comments allude to there's really not much point in trying to replicate the exact behavior of `std::vector` since C lacks templates and [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

What can however be useful is a [dynamic array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) implementation that just works with bytes. This can obviously be used directly for `char*` strings, but can also easily be adapted for usage with any other types as long as you're careful to multiply the size parameter by `sizeof(the_type)`.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Portable Runtime](http://apr.apache.org) has a decent set of [array functions](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.4/group__apr__tables.html) and is all C.

See the [tutorial](http://dev.ariel-networks.com/apr/apr-tutorial/html/apr-tutorial-19.html) for a quick intro.

Answer (score 0):

If you can multiply, there's really no need for a vector_create() function when you have malloc() or even calloc(). You just have to keep track of two values, the pointer and the allocated size, and send two values instead of one to whatever function you pass the "vector" to (if the function actually needs both the pointer and the size, that is). malloc() guarantees that the memory chunk is addressable as any type, so assign it's `void *` return value to e.g. a `struct car *` and index it with `[]`. Most processors access `array[index]` almost as fast as `variable`, while a vector_at() function can be many times slower. If you store the pointer and size together in a struct, only do it in non time-critical code, or you'll have to index with `vector.ptr[index]`. Delete the space with free().

Focus on writing a good wrapper around realloc() instead, that only reallocates on every power of e.g. 2 or 1.5. See user786653's [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array).

Of course, calloc(), malloc() and realloc() can fail if you run out memory, and that's another possible reason for wanting a vector type. C++ has exceptions that automatically terminate the program if you don't catch it, C doesn't. But that's another discussion.

Answer (score -1):

Lack of template functionality in C makes it impossible to support a vector like structure. The best you can do is to define a 'generic' structure with some help of the preprocessor, and then 'instantiate' for each of the types you want to support.

Comment: Or use `void *` and an explicit `size_t element_size`, but that's ugly and error-prone as hell.